# How to delete a complete forum topic from root folder in wordpress

Tags: wp-query

I have a website www.electricdiylab.com  where I have started a topic so after some time it is flooded with spam, so I decide to delete it but I am not able to delete it by traditional way (by clicking on bin please refer attached screenshot)  whenever I clicked on bin to delete forum topic it went on loading until page timeout error occurs,

so how I can delete this junk forum topic from the root folder of my website, I am not using Cpanel I am using FTP protocol  Filezilla to access my root file, [image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot why "Bin" is not working, you'll likely need to contact the plugin author. If it's your own custom plugin/theme/code, please share above and perhaps we can be of more assistance.

Another option might be to close the forum. Again you would need to contact the author to determine whether that is possible or not with the current codebase.

An alternative, manual way to delete the forum would be to use phpMyAdmin to directly edit your database. Be sure to save a backup first, and be sure you understand the structure saved in the database. From your screenshot it appears that a "forum" is simply a custom post type but it's possible that it's more complex than that. If it's a CPT and you hover your cursor over "edit" you should be able to see the post ID in the target URL. You can then log into phpMyAdmin, go to the `(prefix)_posts` table (i.e. `wp_posts`), search for that post ID, and manually delete it. You may then want to use a database optimization plugin which can delete all of that post's orphaned revisions and postmeta, but this would at least remove the post completely.

Comment: thanks to address my issue, 
as this is wordpress default forum facility, I have contact them but they are looks clueless, thanks to guide me about phpMyAdmin, I will try to delete via phpMyAdmin........
hope it  will solve...

Comment: WordPress Core does not contain "forums." You're using some sort of plugin or theme that adds this functionality.

Comment: ohh yes its under plugin called bbPress and was looking for any forum plugin, its done i deactivated plugin and it disappears thanks for great help I have learnt much from this...